# How to list all personal sharepoint sites using microsoft graph?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-files

I want to fetch following data using Microsoft graph API

1. All the root sites(group + personal)
2. All group root sites
3. All personal root sites

For the first case currently I am using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites` in order to find out all the root sites

For the second one I am using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=contentclass:STS_Site` to find out all group sites.

I am not sure how to which API I can use to find out only personal sites. Do graph API have any filter which does that? Also is there a way to solve point 1 and 2 in a better way?

Answer (score -1):

@Mridul Sharma,

Please take a reference of below steps:

1. There is a hidden list called "DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGA" in the admin site. It stores a cached copy of aggregated site collections data from all contentDB.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/lists`

[image]

2. Get all sites

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/lists/90403211-a51b-4a2b-8e83-a569011b63f7/items?$expand=fields`

[image]

3. Use the filter to get all personal sites

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/tenant-admin.sharepoint.com/lists/90403211-a51b-4a2b-8e83-a569011b63f7/items?$expand=fields&$filter=fields/TemplateId eq 21`

BR

Comment: This doesn't work - running the first query does not produce a list called `DO_NOT_DELETE_SPLIST_TENANTADMIN_ALL_SITES_AGGREGA`.